# Why does the "Warning: file(...): failed to open stream" error occur?

Tags: php

Tell me please, why does the "*Warning: file(...): failed to open stream*" error occur in this code?

```
    if (file("users/1/cover_user.png")) {
        echo '<img data-src="users/1/cover_user.png" uk-img>';
    }
    elseif (file("users/1/cover_user.jpg")) {
        echo '<img data-src="users/1/cover_user.jpg" alt="" uk-img>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'error';
    }
```

Comment: Firstly check the path and permissions - is that path correct relative to the calling script and does that script have permission to read it? What's the difference between the `if` and `elseif` there? They both appear to be checking the same condition..?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 users/1/` will change the permissions for those image files

Comment: ^ There is **no** reason to ever `777` **anything** on a web server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) command reads the entire file into memory.

I think that is not what you want. Seems you want to test if a file exists, have a look at [file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) for that test.

That said: Your warning means that PHP cannot find the file at the location. Popular reasons for this are:

1. No file found with that name
2. File is there, but is NOT readable for the user that runs as PHP, often www-data (on linux/gnu systems) or IUSR (on ISS).

Double check your path. And maybe use a full path.

Also your if/elseif/else logic confuses me.

Comment: file_exists helped me. thnks

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that `users/1/cover_user.png` is a correct path?
2. Do you have the read permission to access the file?

If you're on linux try this command:

```
chmod 0444 path/to/your/file/users/1/cover_user.png
```

You can also try this one:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /your/project/path
```

If you're on windows try to set permissions from Properties dialog